# How to Disable Control type Menu in manifest file in office js add-in

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, ribbonx, ribbon-control

IN this [manifest/enabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/enabled?view=common-js-preview) we can disable a `Control` type `Button`.

for example:

```
      <Control xsi:type="Button" id="BtnOpenTaskpane">
        <Label resid="BtnOpenTaskpane.Label" />
         <Supertip>
         <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
          <Title resid="BtnOpenTaskpane.Label" />
           <!-- ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource. -->
           <Description resid="BtnOpenTaskpane.Tooltip" />
         </Supertip>
         <Icon>
            <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16"/>
            <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32"/>
            <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80"/>
         </Icon>
        <!-- This is what happens when the command is triggered Supported actions are ExecuteFunction-->
        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
           <FunctionName>btnopentaskpane</FunctionName>
         </Action>
        <Enabled>false</Enabled> <!--Disable this Control-->
    </Control>
```

Now I have Control type Menu

for example:

```
         <Control xsi:type="Menu" id="Contoso.TaskpaneButton2">
                <Label resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton2.Label" />
            <Supertip>
                <!-- ToolTip title. resid must point to a ShortString resource. -->
               <Title resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton2.Label" />
                <!--ToolTip description. resid must point to a LongString resource.-->
                    <Description resid="Contoso.TaskpaneButton2.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="heading1-16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="heading1-32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="heading1-80" />
                </Icon>
                <Items>
                   <Item id="itemPartTitle">
                     <Label resid="Group2.Item1.Label"/>
                    <Supertip>
                        <Title resid="Group2.Item1.Label" />
                        <Description resid="Group2.Item1.Tooltip" />
                    </Supertip>
                    <Icon>
                      <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                      <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                      <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                    </Icon>
                        <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                            <FunctionName>PartTitle</FunctionName>
                        </Action>
                    </Item>
                </Items>
      
               <!--Here We can't Add <Enabled>false</Enabled>-->
            </Control>
```

I think we can't disable a `Control` type `Menu` because it have not `Action`.

In this case I think we can Disable a `Menu` `Item`.

```
            <Items>
               <Item id="itemPartTitle">
                 <Label resid="Group2.Item1.Label"/>
                <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="Group2.Item1.Label" />
                    <Description resid="Group2.Item1.Tooltip" />
                </Supertip>
                <Icon>
                  <bt:Image size="16" resid="Contoso.tpicon_16x16" />
                  <bt:Image size="32" resid="Contoso.tpicon_32x32" />
                  <bt:Image size="80" resid="Contoso.tpicon_80x80" />
                </Icon>
                    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                        <FunctionName>PartTitle</FunctionName>
                    </Action>
                   <Enabled>false</Enabled>
                </Item>
```

Here Again a question can we `Enable` `Item`

```
 function enableButton() {
   Office.ribbon.requestUpdate({
     tabs: [
            {
             id: "OfficeAppTab1", 
             groups: [
                 {
                   id: "CustomGroup111",
                   controls: [
                     {
                         id: "MyButton", 
                         enabled: true
                     }
                   ]
                 }
             ]
         }
      ]
  });
}
```

In this we have controls to Enable is that work fro Item

Comment: What is your host application?

Comment: I have Word Add-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling and disabling custom add-in commands (buttons and menu items) dynamically are currently supported, see [Enable and Disable Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/disable-add-in-commands) for more information.

To test for support, your code should call `Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('RibbonApi', '1.1')`. If, and only if, that call returns `true`, your code can call the enable/disable APIs. If the call of `isSetSupported` returns `false`, then all custom add-in commands are enabled all of the time. You must design your production add-in, and any in-app instructions, to take account of how it will work when the `RibbonApi 1.1` requirement set isn't supported. For more information and examples of using isSetSupported, see [Specify Office applications and API requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements), especially [Runtime checks for method and requirement set support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#runtime-checks-for-method-and-requirement-set-support).